# How to get the Quotient of every row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
A 
2 
6 
12
```

Now I like to get a new Column B with the Quotient of the Rows of A and B:

```
A  B 
2  3
6  2
12 -
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [2, 6, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['B'] = df['A'] / df['A'].shift(1)
df['B'] = df['B'].shift(-1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A    B
0   2  3.0
1   6  2.0
2  12  NaN
```

**EDIT:**

Shorter version: `df['B']= df['A'].shift(-1).div(df['A'])`
It gives the same output.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [2, 6, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['B']= df['A'].shift(-1).div(df['A'])
print(df)
```

Comment: No need to shift twice, `df['A'].shift(-1).div(df['A'])` is enough

Comment: @mozway I added it (after the editing part), thanks.